# Picture/Table Tools does not appear on the ribbon in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have a Worksheet that contains a picture and a table. I also have a UserForm that acts as a countdown timer. The UserForm contains the following piece of code:

```
Option Explicit
Const AllowedTime As Double = 10 ' Total time in minutes

Private Sub UserForm_Activate()

Dim T, E, M, S As Double

T = Timer

Do
    E = CDbl(Time) * 24 * 60 * 60 - T
    M = AllowedTime - 1 - Int(E / 60)
    S = 59 - Round((E / 60 - Int(E / 60)) * 60, 0)
    
    TimeLabel.Caption = Format(CStr(M), "00") & ":" & Format(CStr(S), "00")
    
    DoEvents
Loop Until (Timer - T) / 60 >= AllowedTime   

MsgBox "Time Over!"
Unload Me

End Sub
```

The above code is not mine. I found it on an Excel forum. It just displays a countdown timer of 10 minutes, and when the time runs out, the userform unloads.

The problem is that while the userform is running, when I click the picture or the table in the worksheet, the Picture Tools/Table Tools that normally appear on the ribbon does not appear. I inserted a chart, and the Chart Tools doesn't appear too.

I found out that when I run the userform by commenting out the above timer code, everything works perfectly. I tried opening the Excel file in 3 different PCs, and all of them showed the same problem. Is there anything wrong with the timer code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happens because of the `Do-Loop`. It is not restricted to just `Picture Tools/Table Tools` but also to other menus like `PivotTable Tools`.

Here is an example to replicate your problem. When the loop is running then the menu will not show. Paste this code in a module.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim loopCount As Long
    
    Do
        loopCount = loopCount + 1
        
        '~~> Wait for 1 second
        Wait 1
        
        If loopCount > 15 Then Exit Sub
    Loop
End Sub

Private Sub Wait(ByVal nSec As Long)
    nSec = nSec + Timer
    While nSec > Timer
        DoEvents
    Wend
End Sub
```

Instead of using a loop, you can use `Application.OnTime` to show the timer. Here is an example. BTW there are APIs as well for handling timer in VBA.

**Caution**:

Make a backup of your data or use a new workbook before you work with  or test timers.

**Userform Code:**

Insert a new userform. Let's call it `frmTimer`. Put one label on it. Let's call it `TimeLabel`. Now paste this code in the userform.

```
Option Explicit

Dim nextMoment As Date

Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
    Timer_Event
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
    Timer_Stop
End Sub

Sub Timer_Event()
    nextMoment = Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")
    Application.OnTime nextMoment, "Module1.OnTimer"
End Sub

Sub Timer_Stop()
    Application.OnTime nextMoment, "Module1.OnTimer", Schedule:=False
End Sub

Public Sub OnTimer()
    TimeLabel.Caption = Time
    Timer_Event
End Sub
```

**Module Code:**

Insert a module. Let's call it `Module1`. (*This should be the name by default if this is a new workbook*). Paste this code there

```
Option Explicit

Sub OnTimer()
    frmTimer.OnTimer
End Sub

Sub ShowForm()
    frmTimer.Show vbModeless
End Sub
```

Now run `Sub ShowForm()`. You will see that the menu doesn't disappear now.

**In Action**

[image]